# c# linq join multiple table with order based on first table id with group by

Tags: c#, linq, join, left-join, sql-order-by

i want to do order by based on first table in left join c# linq

i've 3 table
TDoctorAppointments 
TDoctors 
TDoctor_Clinic

left join on TDoctorAppointments with group by first of TDoctorAppointment_TDoctorID_DID

till now i got this query success but order of TDoctorAppointment_TDoctorID_DID is not maintained.

i want to order the result on TDoctorAppointment_TDoctorID_DID

Here is my code

```
var list2 = (from d in db.TDoctorAppointments
                             orderby d.TDoctorAppointment_TDoctorID_DID
                             join dcs in db.TDoctors on d.TDoctorAppointment_TDoctorID_DID equals dcs.TDoctor_DID
                             into dcs1
                             from dcs2 in dcs1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             join doc1 in db.TDoctor_Clinic on d.TDoctorAppointment_TDoctorID_DID equals doc1.TDoctor_Clinic_DID
                             into doc2
                             from doc3 in doc2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             where d.TDoctorAppointment_Tpatient_PID == patData
                             select new
                             {
                                 DID = d.TDoctorAppointment_TDoctorID_DID,
                                 Name = dcs2.TDoctor_FirstName,
                                 Latitude = doc3.TDoctor_Clinic_Latitude,
                                 Longitude = doc3.TDoctor_Clinic_Longitude
                             }).ToList();
var firs1 = list2.GroupBy(g => g.DID).Select(s => s.First());
```

( Code Format is bad i know :p)

Thanks :)

Comment: You have a left outer join (from dcs2 in dcs1.DefaultIfEmpty())  So what do you expect when TDoctorAppointment_TDoctorID_DID doesn't contain the ID and one of the other table do contain a new ID?   I believe the issue is with the case when TDoctorAppointment_TDoctorID_DID is null.

Comment: Why are you ordering at the start of your query, rather than at the end?

Comment: FYI If you have FK relationships setup you should have navigation properties that you can use instead of all those joins.  It would look something like `from dc2 in d.TDoctors.DefaultIfEmpty()` instead of the join-into-from.

Comment: The `orderby` should be last if you expect SQL / LINQ to honor it.

Comment: problem solved, thanks for the help.